# Class Not Found Exception Error

Tags: symfony

I just upgraded a project's Symfony framework from 2.3 to 2.7

But now I ran into an error:

```
Class Not Found Exception in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4227: 
Attempted to load class "Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text" from the global 
namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

I am pretty new to Symfony and a lot of stuff are still quite overwhelming for me. Can somebody please help me out with this?

Thank you

Comment: i know its old, but i run into this again, and i dont want to use the outdated lib. 
i found a service with the class "Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text" in my "services.yml".. just remove it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This class doesn't come with the `twig/twig` package, but with the `twig/extensions` package ([docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/index.html)).

Make sure you have this package installed by running `composer show -i` and searching (or by using grep) in the output for this package name.

If you haven't, install the package:

```
$ composer require twig/extensions
```